# Query python systemd.journal like journalctl -b and journalctl --list-boots for entries related to last boots

Tags: python, systemd, systemd-journald

I'm looking for a way to query the information provided by `journalctl -b` and `journalctl --list-boots` through python systemd module.

I've written a workaround which runs journalctl as a subprocess and parses the output. Maybe there's some more obvious way.

```py
import datetime
import re
import subprocess
from systemd import journal

def parse_datetime_data(data):
    datetimedata_no_tz = data[0:data.rindex(" ")]
    datetimedata_tz = data[data.rindex(" ")+1:-1]

    datetimeValue = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetimedata_no_tz, 
                                               "%a %Y-%m-%d %X")
    return datetimeValue, datetimedata_tz

def get_bootlines():
    bootlinesRaw = subprocess.check_output(['journalctl', '--list-boots', 
                                            '--no-pager'],
                                           encoding="utf-8").splitlines()
    boots = {}

    for bootlineRaw in bootlinesRaw:
        if bootlineRaw:
            lt = re.findall('^ *(-?\d+) (\w+) ([\w -:]+).([\w -:]+)',
                            bootlineRaw)
            linedata = lt[0]

            startdata = linedata[2]
            bootstart,bootstart_tz = parse_datetime_data(startdata)

            enddata = linedata[3]
            bootend,bootend_tz = parse_datetime_data(enddata)

            boots[int(linedata[0])] = {"BOOT_ID":linedata[1],
                                 "start": bootstart, "start_tz": bootstart_tz,
                                 "end": bootstart, "end_tz": bootend_tz}

    return boots

boots = get_bootlines()
```

Comment: For future reference, see `subprocess.check_output()` – you don't need to poll and read a subprocess by hand just to get the output...

Comment: No need to decode by hand either. `check_output(..., encoding="utf-8").splitlines()` :)

Comment: (Also, if you don't want to bother with parsing timezones, set the `TZ=UTC` envvar when you call `journalctl` and it will output UTC times.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of it, neither [`systemd.journal`](https://github.com/systemd/python-systemd/blob/661ee278e801ea072508d7154696440632f894a0/systemd/journal.py) or the underlying [native module](https://github.com/systemd/python-systemd/blob/661ee278e801ea072508d7154696440632f894a0/systemd/_journal.c) expose an API for listing boots.

(You can [use the `_BOOT_ID` matcher](https://github.com/systemd/python-systemd/blob/main/systemd/journal.py#L385) for the journal reader API once you do have a boot id at hand though.)

Looking at the [source for `journalctl`, what `--list-boots` does](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/3d83c3eacfe73b97af3b760afe96d26e74eda5d5/src/journal/journalctl.c#L1272-L1440) is it iterates over all known journal entries and keeps the unique boot IDs and their first and last timestamps, so you could do that in your Python code too.

As an aside, with [systemd >= 251](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/5a1355d848a0f6564a04c6d8268e72bc93d173de) you can just do

```
>>> import json
>>> import subprocess
>>> json.loads(subprocess.check_output(["journalctl", "--output=json", "--list-boots"]))
[{'index': 0, 'boot_id': '5ab8a0b2e2624bcdba4d51d83a7a4fe2', 'first_entry': 1658396953303255, 'last_entry': 1662635352510679}]
```

Comment: The json subprocess suggestion is pretty cool!

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful information!